# Function return value returns as undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function getRent(rent){
    var rent = 666;
    return rent;
}
function show(){

getRent();
alert(rent);
}
```

Why is this not working? It comes out as `rent` undefined?

Comment: Why are you passing in a `rent` parameter to `getRent()`?

Comment: You should read this post to get a better understanding of scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with this code.

For one you are redefining the rent variable by using the var keyword in your getRent function.

Secondly when you call getRent you are not assigning its return value to anything and you are effectively asking the console to display an undefined variable.

What you want is

```
function getRent(){
    var rent = 666;
    return rent;
}

var rent = getRent();
alert(rent);
```

or perhaps

```
function getRent(rent){
    rent = 666;
    return rent;
}

var param = 1; //sample variable to change
var rent = getRent(param);
alert(rent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't assigning the return value of `getRent()` to anything. `rent` is only defined in the `getRent` function.

```
var rent = getRent();
alert(rent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You define `rent` in `getRent()` and not in `show()`. So `rent` is not defined in your case.

Try :

```
function getRent(rent){
    var rent = 666;
    return rent;
}
function show(){
  alert(getRent("params"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the returned value of getRent().

```
function getRent(){
    var rent = 666;
    return rent;
}
function show(){
    var theRent = getRent();
    alert(theRent);
}
```

The reason it doesn't work as you expected is because `rent`, defined inside `getRent`, is not accessible outside of the function. Variables declared inside functions using the `var` keyword are only "visible" to other code inside that same function, unless you return the value to be stored in a variable elsewhere.

It may help you to read up on the basics of functions and function parameters in JavaScript. Here is a good article: http://web-design-weekly.com/blog/2013/01/20/introduction-to-functions-in-javascript/